# html5 block link styling issues

Tags: html, css, background-color

Hi HTML5 / css guru'es

I'm trying to make use of some "new" features presented by HTML5 however I have stumpled uppon a problem with changing my links background on hover when having block elements inside the  tag.

This is my test code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>teeeest</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="saninetto1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <style>
        a:link  { background-color: red; }
        a:hover { background-color: #333; }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
        <div><a href="#">I'm a block</a></div><br />
        <a href="#2"><div>I'm a block 2</div></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

According to html5doctor ([article](http://html5doctor.com/block-level-links-in-html-5/)) it should be straight forward but I just can't change the background on when hovering.

I made this fiddle to show the difference when using my test html: http://jsfiddle.net/vJEEn/

As the fiddle shows I can make changes to the text, but not the background-color

hope you can help me changing the background on hover

Comment: From your fiddle I see the `<a>` with the `<div>` in it has dimensions of 0px x 0px, so you wouldn't be able to see any background, this is probably the effect of putting a block level element inside an inline element.

Comment: I've updated the answer, the modified CSS shall work

Comment: I tried to insert the following css with no effect: div {height: 50px; width:200px; }
So changing the div size doesn't seem to work

Comment: I've updated the answer, check it again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this CSS property in your code.

```
a { display: block;}
```

I think thats what you are looking for.

[test code](http://jsfiddle.net/GZCcC/3/)

better options:

```
a { display: inline-block;}
```

Answer (score 2):

minor change in your code is working in my all browser. code is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>teeeest</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="saninetto1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<style>
    a:link  { background-color: red; }
    a:hover { background-color: #333; color: red;}
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div><a href="#">I'm a block</a></div><br />
     <div><a href="#2"><span>I'm a block 2<span></a></div>
</body>
</html>
```

try this code.

Comment: you seem to have missed the point.. I wanted have the div INSIDE the <a></a> in order to make a block of content into a link

Comment: it provides you block of content and background is also working on hover.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot place a div inside anchor ... Anchors are inline elements cannot include block-level elements within.

This will not validate

```
    <a href="#2"><div>I'm a block 2</div></a>
```

You should change it to

```
    <div><a href="#2">I'm a block 2</a></div>
```

and it will wor

**EDIT**

I read what you attached and found that it's valid on HTML5

You should change your CSS to :

```
    a:hover div { background-color: #333; color: red;}
```

and it will change

**EDIT**

Try this CSS :

```
    a:hover,
    a:hover div { background-color: #333; color: red;}
```

See it on [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vJEEn/2/)

Comment: as of html5 you can.. xhtml and html4 doesn't support it, which is why I'm going for html5

Comment: Thx! I made use of this and then switched the div with * in order to hit all elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `background-color: inherit;` to DIV style

```
<a href=""><div style="background-color: inherit;">I'm a block 2</div></a>​
```

Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nalaka526/vJEEn/4/)

Comment: nice solution, but I went with the less code demanding solution :) but +1 from here

Answer (score 1):

Adding this line in your css it will also work

```
a:hover > div { background-color: #333; display: inline-block }
```

[**SEE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/vJEEn/5/)

but You cannot place a div inside an anchor, it will not validated by w3c.